# Server is not rendering expected page. Can anyone tell what is wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I'm new to programming... I trying to validate login details. But the expected output is not loading(took too much time to respond) below is my code...

```
    app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
       res.render("login");
     });

    app.post("/login", function (req, res) {
     const username = req.body.email;
     const password = req.body.Password;

      User.findOne({ email: username }, (err, foundUser) => {
        if (err) {
         console.log(err);
           } else {
               if (foundUser) {
                 if (foundUser.password === password) {
                     res.render("secrets");
             }
            }
          }
      });
   });
```

If the login operation is successful the page should go to the secrets page. This is a course tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You never send a response in case of an error or if no user is found, which will result in a hanging request. You should do something like this:

```
User.findOne({ email: username }, (err, foundUser) => {
        if (err) {
             console.log(err);
             // redirect to an error page, e.g.
             res.render("someErrorPage");
           } else {
                 if (foundUser && foundUser.password === password) {
                     res.render("secrets");
                 }else {
                     res.render("someErrorPage");
                 }
             }
            }
          }
      });
```